# Building iPhone apps for the iPad

Tags: iphone, ipad

I searched first, so apologies if it's already been asked.

I have a couple iPhone apps that I want to run as native iPad apps rather than in "mini-mode" for lack of a better term.

What do I need to change to build my app for the iPad and is it easy to target both platforms from the same project?

Comment: Just a quick reminder that all of this is meant to be under NDA. iPad SDK specific questions should be asked at http://devforums.apple.com and no-where else until the NDA is lifted.

Comment: Good point. I thought this would be benign enough, but I suppose it's always good to be sure. I did find the unhelpful answer in the NDAed documentation. I'll elaborate when Apple let's me.

Comment: Note that anybody can ask any questions they want. People under NDA are not supposed to answer, but that's between them and Apple. No Stack Overflow user needs to act as the NDA police.

Comment: lol where did this NDA business come from?

Comment: @abbood Those comments are three years old. At the time, the iPad had not yet been released and the SDK was protected by an NDA.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's easy to target both platforms. If you login to ADC and read the iPad Programming Guide, it'll provide the basics for iPad specific development. I can't legally speak of the "how."

Um. If you follow their directions, build two targets, share your source within the same project... then you'll be set. It's the same SDK, just different Nibs & main(), from what I can tell.

Comment: When I build, I have to choose an Active Target to build for, either iPhone or iPad. Does that mean I'll need to provide two builds in order for iPad to, say, load the right nibs?

Comment: You can target both in the same build. XCode will handle everything for you. Give this a read: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this isn't very helpful on a technical level, but...

The new [iPad SDK](http://www.apple.com/ipad/sdk/) site specifically mentions the term "Universal Applications" with the following:

> Developers can now start planning for
>   universal applications, allowing them
>   to take full advantage of the
>   technologies found on iPad, iPhone,
>   and iPod touch with a single binary.

I know this doesn't explain ''how'' to take advantage of this idea, but I'm not quite willing to drop 100 dollars to learn more just yet.

But this does resolve your core goal, which is designing apps that can work nativly on both devices. With the a universal binary, you wouldn't need to worry about covering idiosyncrasies for two versions of one project unless you wanted device-specific features.