# How does deployment of both iPhone and iPad works?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios

I got my iPad yesterday, once synced all iPhone apps synced to iPad. Some of the apps "auto" adjusted to the iPad format while other where in iPhone format. How does that technically work? Or rephrase: How do I as app developer deploy both iPad och iPhone at once for both formats with that "auto" behavior?

BR

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create Universal apps in iPhone/iPad? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3845478/how-to-create-universal-apps-in-iphone-ipad)

Comment: See also [Building iPhone apps for the iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2166742/building-iphone-apps-for-the-ipad) and [What should I consider to ensure seamless port of my iPhone apps to iPad?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2149453/what-should-i-consider-to-ensure-seamless-port-of-my-iphone-apps-to-ipad)

Comment: Thanks Brad for linking to these posts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each application has a deployment target, which describes on what devices it can be launched. "Adjusted" apps list both iPhone and iPad as their target. In this case application includes icons, images and views for both iPhone and iPad, and the internal logic detects which view should be used depending on the device type.

There is a [tutorial](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/44472) on how to make your apps iPad-compatible.

Answer (score 1):

The applications that do this are so-called Universal applications; they include interface definitions for both iPad and iPhone formats and their Info.plist files are also configured as such.

Starting from the Window-Based Application Template in Xcode should demonstrate the configuration and setup nicely.

Most of the time, if you already have an existing iPhone application it is highly likely that you will be better off making a separate HD version of your app, both fiscally and technically, but if you are creating a new application, Universal could very well be the way to go.